# ASP.net Ajax tab container not appearing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, controls

I created new web project using VS 2008 with enabled Ajax template with C# and Framework 3.5.

I added Ajax reference to the project and I can see all Ajax toolkit in my tool box.

The problem that when I add tab container with Tab Panels then run the projects nothing appear on the browser and I tried few browsers.

I'm including my code and I wish that someone would help me.

Regards,

My Code:
................................................................

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Contacts._Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <div>

                <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">

                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                          tab 1
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>

                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2" ID="TabPanel2">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                          tab 2
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>

                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3" ID="TabPanel3">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                          tab 3
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>

                </asp:TabContainer>

            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `<asp:scriptmanager>`, try using `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>`. I found I had problems with the AJAX Accordion when using the original scriptmanager, so this may be a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you Tenaciouslmpy for your reply I played with namespace and it worked with me 
but I changed it to  `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`

Thank again a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` instead of `<asp:scriptmanager>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do Not Set first tab to visible=false or

Or use cheap trick just below tabContainer add javascript

Basically TabContainer is rendered as a div tag, get the div id and remove style attribute.
This was not an issue in AjaxControlToolKit1.0.abcd the lower version but only started in version 3.x

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ctl00_content_profileListTab").removeAttr("style");
    });
</script>
```